# How to import a project from GitLab to IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, gitlab

I know how to clone a project from GitHub to IntelliJ, but I need to clone a project from GitLab.

The problem is, Intellij does not have a GitLab option?

As far as I can see, it only supports Git, Mercurial and Subversion.

[image]

You can find the version of IntelliJ in the below image:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2 (Community Edition)]

How can I import a GitLab project into IntelliJ?

Comment: Use your command line to clone the project (git clone <url>), then open the project. Oh, ang you're confusing git and github. The first option in your screenshot is Git. Both Github and Gitlab use git.

Comment: @JBNizet i know i can use my command line, but i wish to use `Intelij` since it is the standard in my workplace.

Comment: And also, this is ridiculous. IntelliJ doesn't do anything other than what you would do with the command line: clone the project and then open it.

Comment: In case you missed it: Try the “Git” option in that menu.

Answer (score 3):

GitLab is a Git-repository manager (just like GitHub), so importing a GitLab project is the same as importing a Git project.

Once you have chosen the `Project from Version Control` option, click `Git` and provide a repository url (which is obtainable on project's page via `Clone` button).

If you have any doubts, check IntelliJ's [manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/set-up-a-git-repository.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just few clicks...
File --> New --> Project from Version Control…
[image]

and insert the Clone URI of your remote repo, e.g. https://gitlab.com/user101/myproject1.git
[image]

Read more at:
Git - Help | IntelliJ IDEA
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-git-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GitLab Projects plugin or just use the command line.